# pandas dataframe group by uneven timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of market prices, timestamps are in microsecond, eg.

```
Time       Bid
0  2014-03-03 23:30:30.224323  0.892500
1  2014-03-03 23:30:30.224390  0.892525
2  2014-03-03 23:30:30.224408  0.892525
3  2014-03-03 23:30:30.364299  0.892525
4  2014-03-03 23:30:31.022652  0.892500
5  2014-03-03 23:30:31.022702  0.892525
6  2014-03-03 23:30:31.866949  0.892525
7  2014-03-03 23:30:33.366843  0.892525
8  2014-03-03 23:30:33.858239  0.892525
9  2014-03-03 23:30:34.360997  0.892525
10 2014-03-03 23:30:35.034307  0.892525
11 2014-03-03 23:30:36.110848  0.892525
12 2014-03-03 23:30:36.359973  0.892525
13 2014-03-03 23:30:38.111191  0.892525
14 2014-03-03 23:30:41.599924  0.892525
15 2014-03-03 23:30:41.599972  0.892500
```

How do I group by Time by strip away microsecond, for example,
how to convert a OHLC(open, high, low, close) structure of evenly time slot(1min, 5mins, 1hour etc), and also counts for each time slot? I tried to add another column with

```
e['Time2'] = pd.to_datetime(e.Time, format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

dropping %f, but Time2 column looks identical to Time column.

Many thanks,

how to convert it into something like

Comment: I guess I forgot resample function, but how about a generic function(or lambda). Also, resample methods are limited, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the datetime the index so that you can resample:

```
In [11]: df = df.set_index('Time')

In [12]: df.resample('5min', how='ohlc')
Out[12]:
                        Bid
                       open      high     low   close
Time
2014-03-03 23:30:00  0.8925  0.892525  0.8925  0.8925
```

*Note: Unfortunately `to_datetime` doesn't raise if it fails (at least by default) so it often a good idea to check the dtype of the column is datetime64...*

Comment: How do I apply a count function? like   how= ???) Hmmm, I figured out, it's np.size

Comment: @bbc would be good question or issue on gihub, tbh not sure myself!